# How to get MacVim to autoload ~/.vim/syntax

Tags: terminal, macvim

This might be something quirky about MacVim, so I'll ask here.

I put a syntax file in `~/.vim/syntax`, but it doesn't load. I have `syntax on` in my `.vimrc`.

When I open the editor, `:scriptnames` doesn't include the syntax file.

Is there anything else I need to do to make sure it loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to relying on the detected filetype, which may be incorrect, there are at least two alternative ways to force loading of a particular syntax file.

1. Manually run the command `:set ft=lesscss`
2. Add the previous setting to a modeline near the beginning or ending of the file.  See `:help modeline`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It seems like files in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax are loaded based on the detected filetype when the actual file is loaded.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading

So I just renamed the file to the detected filetype, `lesscss`, and it loaded fine.